# html  абсолютные и относительные ссылки

Tags: html

у меня есть папка script и папка html которые лежат в одной папке. В папке html есть страница registration.php которая должна отправлять форму в register.php который лежит в папке script. Написал:

```
<form method="post" action="../script/register.php"></form>
```

в чем ошибка? если он ссылается на

```
/html/script/register.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Относительные пути в html](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#resolving-relative-uris) вычисляются относительно базового адреса, который не обязательно совпадает с адресом текущей страницы. Например, может быть явно задан тегом `<BASE href=... >`. Поэтому лучше, может, абсолютный путь указать?

Из вопроса не вполне понятна структура папок.

Comment: www/cgi-bin/register.php
www/html/registration.php
www/index.php
вот так расположены
индекс.пхп ссылается на регистрацион.пхп, а регистрацион.пхп на регистр.пхп

Comment: я понял что такое BASE но не совсем разобрался как он работает. я прописываю в хэд абсолютный адрес?или же можно относительный?от корня сайта?и как к нему ссылаться после объявления адреса?

Comment: Вы уверены, что корень веб-сайта у вас в `www/`, а не `www/html/`, например? Обычно `cgi-bin` находится во вне, но веб сервером представляется как будто в `site.com/cgi-bin/`.

Для описанных папок, в `registration.php` путь к `register` будет выглядеть `../../cgi-bin/register.php`

Тег [`<base>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) пишется в `<head>`.

Comment: напишу весь путь O:\home\emektep.kz\www\html\registration.php
O:\home\emektep.kz\www\cgi-bin\register.php
O:\home\emektep.kz\www\index.php

Comment: решил забить на эти ссылки.и вписать пхп код в саму страницу